# Integrated square difference of Brownian bridges

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am doing some work with measuring the distance between distributions, and someone pointed out to me that I should look into calculating the integrated squared difference of two brownian bridge processes. Rather than re-invent the wheel, what I would like to ask is if there are any known results for the integrated squared difference of two brownian bridge processes (does it have a known distribution)? In particular,

$$\int_0^1(B_{1t} - B_{2t})^2dt$$

where $B_{1t}$ and $B_{2t}$ are independent brownian bridge processes.

Comment: Are the two Brownian bridges independent? If yes, there difference is $\sqrt{2}$ times a Brownian bridge, so the distribution is the same as $2\int_0^1 B_t^2 dt$, where $B$ is a Brownian bridge.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan the two bridge processes can be assumed to be independent.  Is it straightforward to show what you stated, or is there literature on this? The  natural follow-up question would be does the integral $\int_0^1B_t^2dt$ have a closed form (or known distribution)?

Comment: See https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-30/issue-1/On-the-Distribution-of-the-Square-Integral-of-the-Brownian/10.1214/aop/1020107767.full

Answer (score 2):

For every Gaussian centered process $X$, if one takes an independent copy $X'$, then the process $X+X'$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt{2}X$ (to see that, compare their finite dimensional marginals).

I found this reference
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-30/issue-1/On-the-Distribution-of-the-Square-Integral-of-the-Brownian/10.1214/aop/1020107767.full?tab=ArticleFirstPage

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on your solution, i.e., showing that it is indeed $\sqrt{2}B_t$. I know you give a reason above, but it still eludes me. Or rather, is a Gaussian centered process a brownian bridge?

Comment: If $X$ and $X'$ are independent Gaussian random variable with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,C)$, the distribution of $X+X'$ (and also $X-X'$) is $\mathcal{N}(0,2C)$, so $X+X'$ (and also $X-X'$) has the same distribution as $\sqrt{2}X$.  The same holds for centered Gaussian processes since their distribution is determined by finite-dimensional distributions. In particular, this holds for Brownian bridge, Brownian motion, Ornstein Uhlenbeck processes.